# trouble with IBOutlet.fiboResult.text = @"%d", name();

Tags: ios, objective-c

So i'm making this program, but one line just isn't working. On the line that says `IBOutlet.fiboResult.text = @"%d", name();` I get the error *Expected identifier or '('.* I also tried putting that line outside of the name method.

```
#import "XYZViewController.h"

@interface XYZViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *fiboResult;

@end

@implementation XYZViewController
@synthesize fiboResult;

NSString *fiboNumber = @"%d",*fiboText;
void name() {
    int i;
    int f1 = 1;
    int f2 = 0;
    int fn;
    while (i <= fiboNumber){
        fn = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = fn;
    }
    IBOutlet.fiboResult.text = @"%d", name(); //this line gets the error
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the logic. but are you trying to do something like this:

```
    __block int fiboNumber = [self.fiboResult.text intValue];
int (^name)() = ^(){
    int i;
    int f1 = 1;
    int f2 = 0;
    int fn;
    while (i <= fiboNumber){
        fn = f1 + f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = fn;
    }
    return f2;
};
self.fiboResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", name()]; //this line gets the
```

Comment: It should be `self.fiboResult.text = ...`

Comment: I tried that too, but the error was 'Unknown identifier 'self'"

Comment: @user3817794 Change `name` from a function to an instance method and it will work.

Comment: @Gal Marom I tried your code, but I got 4 errors. 2 on the first line and 2 on the last line.

Comment: @user3817794 I've edited the code - it should be self.fiboResult